# Detect empty variable in PHP not working

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I have been fighting with the following code and variants, but have not been able to come up with anything that works. The idea is that I detect if the variable `$largeimg6` (the URL of an image) is empty or not (whether an image has been loaded) and if not, load the value of a default variable (`$defaultimage`) which holds the URL of a default image..

```
<?php if(!empty($largeimg6)) : ?>
<img class="rpPicture" id="rpPicture<?php echo $key; ?>" onload="showPicture(this, <?php echo SHOW_PICTURES; ?>)" width="60" height="60" src="<?php echo $largeimg6; ?>" alt="Buy CD!" title="Buy CD!" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is that I do not know where to add the arguement for `$largeimg6` being empty and therefore adding:

```
$largeimg6 = $defaultimage
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried is_null() or isset()?

Comment: Where is `$largeimg6` initially set? Will isset (http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) work for you?

Comment: `if (isset($myvar)&&strlen($myvar)>0)`

Comment: Thank you for responding, I have resolved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this before that if statement:

```
<?php $largeimg6 = $largeimg6 != '' ? $largeimg6 : $defaultimage; ?>
```

The `!= ''` comparision may be change according to your need to [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php), [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)(as Ville Rouhiainen suggested) or whatever.

Comment: @omega1 nice, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the alternative (and trim as already suggested):

```
$largeimg6 = trim($largeimg6);
if (isset($largeimg6)&&strlen($largeimg6)>0)
```

but you'll probably be doing better by filtering the url:

```
$largeimg6 = trim($largeimg6);
if(filter_var($largeimg6, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/es/book.filter.php

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

This answer assumes that you have a variable `$largeimg6` which is either going to be set to a url or be [empty](http://php.net/empty).

That being the case it's a fairly simple fix. You need to remove the `if` statement entirely and replace your:

```
<?php echo $largeimg6; ?>
```

with:

```
<?php echo (empty($largeimg6)) ? '/default/image.jpg' : $largeimg6; ?>
```

#### Explanation

The above is equivalent to:

```
if(empty($largeimg6)){
    echo '/default/image.jpg';
}
else{
    echo $largeimg6;
}
```

But in the form:

```
(IF) ? THEN : ELSE;
```